# C++ Queue and Stack Error Unhandled Exception thrown

Tags: c++, queue, stack

This is for my school project. We were prompt to:

1. Add a function on both headers that counts the number of items in the data structure.
2. Use all headers so that:

   a. Populates the queue with any positive number.
   Display the number of items in the queue using the function created at number 1.
   Please use the sample code at main.cpp to randomize numbers.

   b. Inspect each number in the queue.
   Organize it in such a way that even numbers are separated with the odd numbers using stack.
   //implement the queue in to the stack such that the elements that will enter the stack are only
   // even numbers

   c. Create a function at the main program that will compute and display
   the average of either odd or even numbers.
   //the queue will be for add numbers and stack is for the even numbers.

I created multiple queues and stacks to help me separate the odd and even numbers but am having trouble with the display and computation function. MS Visual Studio compiler keeps on stating this error and I am not familiar with it.

[image]

here is my main.cpp code:

```
/******************************************************************************

                             Online C++ Compiler.
              Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include"linkedQueue.h"
#include "linkedStack.h"

using namespace std;

void menu()
{
   cout << "\nDo you want to:\n[1]add a number to the queue"
       <<"\n[2]delete the first item in the queue\n[3]display the number of elements in the queue" << endl;
}

int oddAve(linkedQueueType<int>Odd, linkedQueueType<int>OddCounter)
{
   int num=0,count=0;
   while (!Odd.isEmptyQueue())
   {
       num = num + Odd.front();
       Odd.deleteQueue();
   }
   return num/OddCounter.counterQ(count);
}


int main()
{


   // Providing a seed value
   srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

   // Get a random number
   int random = rand() % 100;

   // Print the random number
   //cout<<"the random number is: "<<random << endl;

   //int addQueNum, option, quit = 0;
   int counterQ = 0;
   int counterS = 0;
   int a = rand() % 100;
   int b = rand() % 100;
   int c = rand() % 100;
   int d = rand() % 100;
   int e = rand() % 100;
   int f = rand() % 100;
   int g = rand() % 100;
   int h = rand() % 100;
   int i = rand() % 100;
   int j = rand() % 100;
   int k = rand() % 100;

   linkedQueueType<int>QueueOrig;//to print original list of random numbers
   linkedQueueType<int>QueueCount;//to print the count of the list of numbers
   linkedQueueType<int>QueueOdd;
   linkedQueueType<int>QueueEven;
   linkedQueueType<int>QueueOddCounter;
   linkedQueueType<int>QueueOdd2;

   linkedStackType<int>StackOdd;
   linkedStackType<int>StackEven;

   int count=0;

   for (auto i : { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k })
   {
       QueueOrig.addQueue(i); 
       QueueCount.addQueue(i);
   }
   for (auto i : { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k })
   {
       if (i % 2 == 0)
       {
           QueueEven.addQueue(i);
           StackEven.push(i);
       }
       else
       {
           QueueOdd.addQueue(i);
           QueueOdd2.addQueue(i);
           QueueOddCounter.addQueue(i);
           StackOdd.push(i);

       }
   }
   
   cout << "the numebers in the list nare: " << endl;
   QueueOrig.printQ();
   
   cout << "\n\nthere are " << QueueCount.counterQ(count) << " elements in the list.";
   
   cout << "\n\nthe odd numebrs are: " << endl;
   QueueOdd.printQ();
   
   cout << "\n\nThe average of the odd numbers is: " << endl;
   oddAve(QueueOdd2,QueueOddCounter);

   cout << "\n\nthe even numbers are: " << endl;
   StackEven.printStack();
   


   
   //return 1;
   system("pause>0");
}
```

here is the linkedQueue.h:

```
//Header file linkedQueue.h
 
#ifndef H_linkedQueue
#define H_linkedQueue 
  
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "queueADT.h"
//#include "linkedList.h"
 
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class linkedQueueType: public queueADT<Type>
{
public:
    const linkedQueueType<Type>& operator=
                    (const linkedQueueType<Type>&); 
      //Overload the assignment operator.

    bool isEmptyQueue() const;
      //Function to determine whether the queue is empty. 
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the queue is empty,
      //               otherwise returns false.
     
    bool isFullQueue() const;
      //Function to determine whether the queue is full. 
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the queue is full,
      //               otherwise returns false.

    void initializeQueue();
      //Function to initialize the queue to an empty state.
      //Postcondition: queueFront = nullptr; queueRear = nullptr

    Type front() const;
      //Function to return the first element of the queue.
      //Precondition: The queue exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: If the queue is empty, the program 
      //               terminates; otherwise, the first 
      //               element of the queue is returned. 

    Type back() const;
      //Function to return the last element of the queue.
      //Precondition: The queue exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: If the queue is empty, the program 
      //               terminates; otherwise, the last 
      //               element of the queue is returned.

    void addQueue(const Type& queueElement);
      //Function to add queueElement to the queue.
      //Precondition: The queue exists and is not full.
      //Postcondition: The queue is changed and queueElement
      //               is added to the queue.

    void deleteQueue();
      //Function  to remove the first element of the queue.
      //Precondition: The queue exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: The queue is changed and the first 
      //               element is removed from the queue.
    
    int counterQ(int counter);
    //counter of the elements in the queue

    void printQ();
    //print the queue

    //oddQueue(linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue);

    linkedQueueType(); 
      //Default constructor

    linkedQueueType(const linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue);
    //Copy constructor

    ~linkedQueueType(); 
      //Destructor

private:
    nodeType<Type> *queueFront; //pointer to the front of 
                                //the queue
    nodeType<Type> *queueRear;  //pointer to the rear of 
                                //the queue

};

    //Default constructor
template <class Type>
linkedQueueType<Type>::linkedQueueType() 
{
    queueFront = nullptr; //set front to nullptr
    queueRear = nullptr;  //set rear to nullptr
} //end default constructor

template <class Type>
bool linkedQueueType<Type>::isEmptyQueue() const
{
    return (queueFront == nullptr);
} //end isEmptyQueue

template <class Type>
bool linkedQueueType<Type>::isFullQueue() const
{
    return false;
} //end isFullQueue

template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::initializeQueue()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;

    while (queueFront!= nullptr)  //while there are elements 
                                  //left in the queue
    {
        temp = queueFront;  //set temp to point to the 
                            //current node
        queueFront = queueFront->link;  //advance first to  
                                        //the next node
        delete temp;    //deallocate memory occupied by temp
    }

    queueRear = nullptr;  //set rear to nullptr
} //end initializeQueue


template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::addQueue(const Type& newElement)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;   //create the node

    newNode->info = newElement; //store the info
    newNode->link = nullptr;    //initialize the link 
                                //field to nullptr

    if (queueFront == nullptr) //if initially the queue is empty
    {
        queueFront = newNode;
        queueRear = newNode;
    }
    else        //add newNode at the end
    {
        queueRear->link = newNode;
        queueRear = queueRear->link;
    }
}//end addQueue

template <class Type>
Type linkedQueueType<Type>::front() const
{
    assert(queueFront != nullptr);
    return queueFront->info; 
} //end front

template <class Type>
Type linkedQueueType<Type>::back() const
{
    assert(queueRear!= nullptr);
    return queueRear->info;
} //end back

template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::deleteQueue()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;
   
    if (!isEmptyQueue())
    {
        temp = queueFront;  //make temp point to the 
                            //first node
        queueFront = queueFront->link; //advance queueFront 

        delete temp;    //delete the first node

        if (queueFront == nullptr) //if after deletion the 
                                   //queue is empty
            queueRear = nullptr;   //set queueRear to nullptr
    }
    else
        cout << "Cannot remove from an empty queue" << endl;
}//end deleteQueue


    //Destructor
template <class Type>
linkedQueueType<Type>::~linkedQueueType() 
{
    //Write the definition of the destructor
} //end destructor

template <class Type>
const linkedQueueType<Type>& linkedQueueType<Type>::operator=
                    (const linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue)
{
    //Write the definition of to overload the assignment operator


} //end assignment operator

    //copy constructor
template <class Type>
linkedQueueType<Type>::linkedQueueType
(const linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue)
{
    //Write the definition of the copy constructor
}//end copy constructor

 // START COUNTER
template <class Type>
int linkedQueueType<Type>::counterQ(int counter)
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;

    while (!isEmptyQueue())
    {
        temp = queueFront;  //make temp point to the 
                            //first node
        counter++;
        queueFront = queueFront->link; //advance queueFront 
        
    }
    
  
    return counter;
} //END COUNTER


 // PRINT
template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::printQ()
{
    nodeType<Type>* temp;

    while (!isEmptyQueue())
    {
        temp = queueFront;
        cout << front() << " ";
       
        deleteQueue();
      
    }

} //END PRINT


#endif
```

Comment: The copy constructor leaves `queueFront` unassigned resulting in UB, should it be used anywhere. `counterQ` should definetly be made `const` which would indicate you accidentally overwriting `queueFront`. Furthermore `initializeQueue` may delete elements without modifying `queueFront`. All of this can result in UB.

Comment: Btw: since you are using references: usually you'd return `Type const&` from `front()` and `back()` which can help avoid unnecessary copies, e.g. in `linkedQueue<std::string> list; ... list.front().size() ...`

Comment: Btw: In debug mode VS does may checks regarding access to memory that "you don't (or no longer) own". This is the cause of you getting this read access violation "exception". Note that this "exception" is not an exception in the sense of an object being passed to `throw`, the debugger realizing Undefined Behaviour is happening here. In release mode probably the program would just have crashed...